# Can i change the name of build.xml in ant?

Tags: ant, build.xml

Can I change the name of build.xml in ant?

```
example- **build_projectname.xml**
```

If yes, how will I run that build file?

Answer (score 3):

You can rename your Ant script to anything you want. You'll just need to add the `-buildfile` option (or `-f` for short) followed by the file name.

`ant -buildfile build_projectname.xml`

`ant -f build_projectname.xml`

See https://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html

It might be more convenient to still have a file named build.xml in the same directory that imports your main script so you don't have to type this extra option every time.